# Trying to find how many spaces in string

Tags: c, char, whitespace, c-strings, counting

I'm trying to find how many spaces(blank strings) are in the sentence[100].

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void){
    
    char sentence[100];
    int count=0;
    scanf("%[^\n]s", sentence);
    
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(sentence);i++){
        if (sentence[i] == 0){
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

I cant find any wrong with this but the result is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

A space, single space, is the character `' '`:

```
if (sentence[i] == ' ')
```

If you want to check for any white-space (space, tab, newline etc.) then use [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace):

```
if (isspace(sentence[i]))
```

The value `0` is the same as the string null-terminator character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this call of scanf

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", sentence);
             ^^^
```

is incorrect. You need to write

```
scanf("%99[^\n]", sentence);
```

The zero value used by you in the if statement

```
    if (sentence[i] == 0){
        count++;
    }
```

is not a space character. The character with the value `0` denotes the end of a string and the function `strlen`  count characters in a character array until a zero character is encountered. So your for loop does not make sense. Either you need to count exactly the space character `' '` or the space character and the tab character `'\t'`.

Using the function `strlen` is inefficient and redundant.

Your program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char sentence[100];
    size_t count = 0;

    if ( scanf( "%99[^\n]", sentence ) == 1 )
    {
        for ( const char *p = sentence; *p != '\0'; ++p )
        {
            if ( *p == ' ' ) ++count;
        }
    }

    printf( "%zu\n", count );

    return 0;
}
```

Or the following way if to count also tab characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    char sentence[100];
    size_t count = 0;

    if ( scanf( "%99[^\n]", sentence ) == 1 )
    {
        for ( const char *p = sentence; *p != '\0'; ++p )
        {
            if ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++count;
        }
    }

    printf( "%zu\n", count );

    return 0;
}
```